# Сниффер JS действий

Tags: javascript, сниффер

Есть ли сниффер JS действий?

Просто у меня есть одна страница, и на ней выполняется `$(this).parent().parent().children().eq(1).html();` и я не могу понять, что она выдаёт.

P.S.

```
function ShowSuperhideII(ms)
 {
 ms.parent().hide();
 message=ms.parent().parent().children().eq(1);
 count=parseInt(ms.parent().parent().children().eq(0).html());
random=Math.floor(Math.random()*110);
 ms.parent().parent().before('<div id="waitB'+random+'"><img width="15px" src="http://***.net/_styles/wait_1.gif"> Подождите пожалуйста...</div>');
 $('#waitB'+random).show();
 $.post('/php/__dehide.php',{HT:message.html(),HC:count,LC:location.href},function(data)
 {
 message.html(data);
 $('#waitB'+random).hide();
 ms.parent().parent().show();
 message.show();
 });
 }
```

Comment: `ms.parent().parent().children()` родовое дерево блин, вам не кажется, что вы делаете что-то не так, если вам приходится так искать узлы? а ещё есть метод [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), а ещё можно идентификаторы задвать, классы и дата-атрибуты

Comment: Этот код не мой, и как можно посмотреть структуру такого древа?

Comment: в этом скрипте идет жесткая привязка к разметке(расположению одних элементов относительно других), что ужасно. если разметка чуть меняется, все плывет. воспользуйтесь инструментами разрабочика для вашего браузера (firebug, dragonfly,...) чтоб увидеть дерево объектов на странице, поставьте breakpoint на этой функции и смотрите какие элементы получаются в ms, message, count... А дальше задайте этим элементам id и в скрипте обращайтесь в этой функции к ним через getElementById. код станет более читаемым и от разметки зависимости будет меньше.

Answer (score 1):

Смотря, что есть сниффер в вашем контексте. [Отладчик есть](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging?hl=n) в каждом браузере, как уже упомянули, в нём можно использоватеть Breakpoints, чтобы изучать состояние объектов по мере выполнения. С дрогой стороны, если нужно наблюдать сложные процессы внутри DOM, вам могут помочь [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) и [Object.observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe).

Answer (score 0):

в хроме -> дев тулс (F12) -> Sources -> Пауза -> F8 для выполнения след команды